# Change last modified time of untarred files

Tags: unix, tar

I am using below command to untar

```
tar -xvf <filename.tar>
```

I want to make sure extracted files' modified time is updated to current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, I found an answer. I looped through all the files in the tar and used touch command to change the modified time.

```
tar -xvf <filename.tar>
for f in $(tar -tf <filename>.tar); do touch $f;done
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU tar has an option for this:

> **`-m`, `--touch`**
>              don't extract file modified time

With this option, extracted files have the time of extraction as their last-modified.